# cache/Unable to load the cache configuration file in Moodle

Tags: moodle

My moodle was installed on Centos 7, disabled selinux but got error "**cache/Unable to load the cache configuration file**"
[[image: error]

How to fix it ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From the Moodle docs

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/RedHat_Linux_installation#SELinux

> Default RedHat Enterprise Linux comes with SELinux set to 'enforcing'. But this may cause user problem accessing web content placed at directory other than the default directory (/var/www/html) or other access problem. If you are not used to SELinux and setting permissions, it's (maybe less secure but) often easier to lower the SELinux level to 'permissive' or even 'disabled'.

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: I did but not work